# Adding .NET Core App to Command Line Path

Tags: c#, .net-core

In the past I made some simple C# command line apps and put them in a directory that I added to my `PATH` environment variable. For example, I made a tool to open a random image from the current directory. The executable for this would be at:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Scripts\RandomImage.exe
```

Then I would navigate to a directory I had a bunch of images in and I could just run this from the command line:

```
L:\Resources\SourceFiles> RandomImage
```

And it would open a random image. How can I do this with .NET Core? I've modified the `project.json` as instructed [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/index).

```
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true
},

"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "version": "1.0.1"
  }
},

"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
},

"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
}
```

Then I run the `publish` command specifying the runtime.

```
dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64
```

With this, I can navigate to the publish directory and run my executable on any Windows 10 (64 bit) machine. But I need the full path to that file in order to run it from any other directory. Is there a way to do this with .NET Core without requiring the full path? I have several of these little apps and I use them from different machines, so I don't want to add an environment variable for each one on each machine.

Comment: Is the publish directory in your `PATH`?

Comment: That's part of the problem. The publish directory has required dlls for the specific app, so I can't put them together with other .NET Core apps in a common directory. I have several of these apps that I use from different machines, so I'm looking for a way that doesn't require me to add a directory to my path for each app on each machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to solve this problem (assuming you have dotnet on your PATH) would be to create a simple CMD script to launch the program.

**Example**

Directory the CMD is in (expected to be on Path): `C:\Users\myuser\Scripts`
Directory you deploy to: `C:\Users\myuser\Scripts\RandomImage`
Name of the CMD file: `RandomImage.cmd`

Content of the CMD file:

```
@dotnet "%~dp0\RandomImage\RandomImage.dll" %*
```

`%~dp0` *is the Path of the script itself*
`%*` *Passes all arguments to the DLL*

You could then use it like this:

```
L:\Resources\SourceFiles> RandomImage arg1 arg2
```